# Equation collage

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to make an equation collage using all the equations within a document?

So far I have exported all the equations with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath]{preview}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 x^2+2x+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 F=\int dx~f(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

to output a file with all the equations without numbering. Then used

```
pdfcrop output.pdf
```

to crop them. However I'm not sure how to proceed next, in order to generate the collage automatically. I have three options:

1. scale each image randomly and then stack them, trying to minimize empty space between the equations. Something like this https://www.kn3.net/ana_caro/35-3-3-6-4-7-3-4-363-JPG.html
2. assign random opacity to each equation and overlap them like https://media.gettyimages.com/vectors/quantum-physics-formulas-over-blackboard-vector-id500260145
3. rotate all images at a angle and have them overlap, creating a background like this 
   https://media.gettyimages.com/vectors/math-background-vector-id165979446

Comment: It is an interesting question.  But it would definitely be helpful for you to provide a full MWE, and not just code fragments.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes done.